# How to wrap text around a path defined in svg (using css)?

Tags: svg, css-shapes

My goal is to wrap some text around a shape defined with svg.

The shape is path looking like a rectangle with a 1/2 circular hole.

```
<svg width="100px" height="200px" viewBox="0 0 50 100">
    <path id="halfcircleLeft" d="M 50 26 ... Z" style="fill: lightgray;"></path>
</svg>
```

In the html, I define the wrapping element with a <div>

```
<div class="svgLeftShape"></div>
```

and I set his css like this:

```
.svgLeftShape
{
    shape-outside: url(#halfcircleLeft);
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

Should work, isn't it?

Well, it is not working as expected!

It sounds like the text is wrapped around the rectangle defined through the css width and height. The shape reference to the svg element is ignored ...

What am I doing wrong?

In the following [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ARTysme/c0q2a1ta/), I have added a 'css' circle on the right just to make sure I was not missing the basics.

Answer (score 3):

> **Warning :**
>
> First, you should know that the [CSS Shapes Module Level 1](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-shapes/) actualy
>   (april 2015) has the status of "Candidate Recommendation". As this
>   means it is a work in progress, it may change at any moment and
>   therefore [shape-outside](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-shapes/#shape-outside-property) should not be used other than for
>   testing.

This property is actualy [only supported by chrome](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/shape-outside#Browser_compatibility) and requires the `-webkit-` vendor prefix that you haven't included in your code.

Here is an example that you **will only be able to view in chrome 37+** :

```css
.shape {
  -webkit-shape-outside: circle(100px);
  shape-outside: circle(100px);
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="shape"></div>
<p>It includes techniques such as applying herbal-infused oils to the body, manual tissue manipulation, deep tissue work, identifying & acting on specific points, mobilizing the joints, and warming the body. It includes techniques such as applying herbal-infused
  oils to the body, manual tissue manipulation, deep tissue work, identifying & acting on specific points, mobilizing the joints, and warming the body. It includes techniques such as applying herbal-infused oils to the body, manual tissue manipulation,
  deep tissue work, identifying & acting on specific points, mobilizing the joints, and warming the body. It includes techniques such as applying herbal-infused oils to the body, manual tissue manipulation, deep tissue work, identifying & acting on specific
  points, mobilizing the joints, and warming the body.</p>
```

### Using images for the shape-outside :

I am not aware wether you can use svg images or not. But you can use .png images and the shape will be generated according to the **transparency of the image** :

```css
img{
  -webkit-shape-outside: url(http://i.imgur.com/yZcQxF6.png);
  shape-outside: url(http://i.imgur.com/yZcQxF6.png);
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/yZcQxF6.png"/>
<p>It includes techniques such as applying herbal-infused oils to the body, manual tissue manipulation, deep tissue work, identifying & acting on specific points, mobilizing the joints, and warming the body. It includes techniques such as applying herbal-infused oils to the body, manual tissue manipulation, deep tissue work, identifying & acting on specific points, mobilizing the joints, and warming the body. It includes techniques such as applying herbal-infused oils to the body, manual tissue manipulation, deep tissue work, identifying & acting on specific points, mobilizing the joints, and warming the body. It includes techniques such as applying herbal-infused oils to the body, manual tissue manipulation, deep tissue work, identifying & acting on specific points, mobilizing the joints, and warming the body It includes techniques such as applying herbal-infused oils to the body, manual tissue manipulation, deep tissue work, identifying & acting on specific points, mobilizing the joints, and warming the body. It includes techniques such as applying herbal-infused oils to the body, manual tissue manipulation, deep tissue work, identifying & acting on specific points, mobilizing the joints, and warming the body. It includes techniques such as applying herbal-infused oils to the body, manual tissue manipulation, deep tissue work, identifying & acting on specific points, mobilizing the joints, and warming the body. It includes techniques such as applying herbal-infused oils to the body, manual tissue manipulation, deep tissue work, identifying & acting on specific points, mobilizing the joints, and warming the body.</p>
```

*Note : If your image has several levels of transparency, you can control which level defines the outline of the shape with the [shape-image-threshold](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/shape-image-threshold) propery.*

---

EDIT: The use of svgs for the shape-outside property is discussed in the [CSS shapes module level 2](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-shapes-2/#referencing-svg-shapes)

Comment: Thank you for your response. This is true that I didn't known I was using 'experimental' properties.

Answer (score 1):

These are experimental features and I would not recommend using them yet since they will only render properly in chrome.

```css
.tri {
  -webkit-shape-outside: polygon(0 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
  float: left;
  width: 40%;
  height: 12ex;
  background-color: lightgray;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
}
.rect {
  -webkit-shape-outside: inset(0 0, 100px 100px 100px 100px);
  width: 100px;
  height: 80px;
  float: left;
  background-color: tomato;
  -webkit-clip-path: inset(0 0, 100px 100px 100px 100px);
}
.circ {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  -webkit-shape-outside: circle(40%);
  shape-outside: circle(40%);
  transition: shape-outside 1s;
  float: left;
  background-color: tomato;
  -webkit-clip-path: circle(40%);
}
.circ:hover {
  -webkit-shape-outside: circle(50%);
  shape-outside: circle(50%);
  -webkit-clip-path: circle(50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="tri"></div>

  <p>
    This is really experimental and "CHROME ONLY", Lorem ipsum dollar si amet, Lorem ipsum dollar si amet, Lorem ipsum dollar si amet, Lorem ipsum dollar si amet, Lorem ipsum dollar si amet, Lorem ipsum dollar si amet, Lorem ipsum dollar si amet, Lorem ipsum
    dollar si amet, Lorem ipsum dollar si amet, Lorem ipsum dollar si amet, Lorem ipsum dollar si amet, Lorem ipsum dollar si amet
  </p>
  <div class="rect"></div>
  <p>
    This is really experimental and "CHROME ONLY", Lorem ipsum dollar si amet, Lorem ipsum dollar si amet, Lorem ipsum dollar si amet, Lorem ipsum dollar si amet, Lorem ipsum dollar si amet, Lorem ipsum dollar si amet, Lorem ipsum dollar si amet, Lorem ipsum
    dollar si amet, Lorem ipsum dollar si amet, Lorem ipsum dollar si amet, Lorem ipsum dollar si amet, Lorem ipsum dollar si amet
  </p>
  <div class="circ"></div>
  <p>
    HOVERING ?! hell yh :D HOVERING ?! hell yh :D HOVERING ?! hell yh :D HOVERING ?! hell yh :D HOVERING ?! hell yh :D HOVERING ?! hell yh :D HOVERING ?! hell yh :D HOVERING ?! hell yh :D HOVERING ?! hell yh :D HOVERING ?! hell yh :D HOVERING ?! hell yh :D
    HOVERING ?! hell yh :D HOVERING ?! hell yh
</div>
```

All of this wil only work in chrome at time of writing unfortunately.
Now the syntax does say that images are allowed.
So this wil only

```css
#image {
  -webkit-shape-outside: url("http://i198.photobucket.com/albums/aa49/Nightlady070/Cliparts/Internet_Explorer_7_Logo_red_zps21ac8b59.png");
  shape-outside: url("http://i198.photobucket.com/albums/aa49/Nightlady070/Cliparts/Internet_Explorer_7_Logo_red_zps21ac8b59.png");
  -webkit-shape-image-threshold: 0.1;
  shape-image-threshold: 0.1;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<img id="image" src="http://i198.photobucket.com/albums/aa49/Nightlady070/Cliparts/Internet_Explorer_7_Logo_red_zps21ac8b59.png" />
<p>Lorem ipsum dollar si amet, Lorem ipsum dollar si amet, Lorem ipsum dollar si amet, Lorem ipsum dollar si amet, Lorem ipsum dollar si amet, Lorem ipsum dollar si amet, Lorem ipsum dollar si amet, Lorem ipsum dollar si amet, Lorem ipsum dollar si amet,
  Lorem ipsum dollar si amet, Lorem ipsum dollar si amet, Lorem ipsum dollar si amet, Lorem ipsum dollar si amet, Lorem ipsum dollar si amet, Lorem ipsum dollar si amet, Lorem ipsum dollar si amet, Lorem ipsum dollar si amet, Lorem ipsum dollar si amet, Lorem ipsum dollar si amet, Lorem ipsum dollar si amet, Lorem ipsum dollar si amet, Lorem ipsum dollar si amet, Lorem ipsum dollar si amet, Lorem ipsum dollar si amet, Lorem ipsum dollar si amet, Lorem ipsum dollar si amet, Lorem ipsum dollar si amet, Lorem ipsum dollar si amet, Lorem ipsum dollar si amet, Lorem ipsum dollar si amet, Lorem ipsum dollar si amet, Lorem ipsum dollar si amet, Lorem ipsum dollar si amet, Lorem ipsum dollar si amet, Loremt, Lorem ipsum dollar si amet, Lorem ipsum dollar si amet, Lorem ipsum dollar si amet, Lorem ipsum dollar si amet, Lorem ipsum dollar si amet, Lorem ipsum dollar si amet, Lorem ipsum dollar si amet, Lorem ipsum dollar si amet, Lorem ipsum dollar si amet, Lorem ipsum dollar si amet</p>
```

**Now to SVG images** SVG as shape [draft](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-shapes-2/#referencing-svg-shapes)
Seems there is no support for this element yet, since it only finds the outer most svg and not the shape elements.

```css
#image {
  -webkit-shape-outside: url("http://images3.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20120330024139/logopedia/images/d/d7/Google_Chrome_logo_2011.svg");
  shape-outside: url("http://images3.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20120330024139/logopedia/images/d/d7/Google_Chrome_logo_2011.svg");
  -webkit-shape-image-threshold: 0.1;
  shape-image-threshold: 0.1;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<img id="image" src="http://images3.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20120330024139/logopedia/images/d/d7/Google_Chrome_logo_2011.svg" />
<p>Lorem ipsum dollar si amet, Lorem ipsum dollar si amet, Lorem ipsum dollar si amet, Lorem ipsum dollar si amet, Lorem ipsum dollar si amet, Lorem ipsum dollar si amet, Lorem ipsum dollar si amet, Lorem ipsum dollar si amet, Lorem ipsum dollar si amet,
  Lorem ipsum dollar si amet, Lorem ipsum dollar si amet, Lorem ipsum dollar si amet, Lorem ipsum dollar si amet, Lorem ipsum dollar si amet, Lorem ipsum dollar si amet, Lorem ipsum dollar si amet, Lorem ipsum dollar si amet, Lorem ipsum dollar si amet,
  Lorem ipsum dollar si amet, Lorem ipsum dollar si amet, Lorem ipsum dollar si amet, Lorem ipsum dollar si amet</p>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. As you said "this is draft... there is no support for this yet,  ... and it does not find the shape element". Thanks again!

Comment: @JosephMarie i think thats the case. If you find a way to make it work, do tell :)